# What's the algorithm behind Robocopy?

Tags: .net, file-io, .net-4.0, robocopy

I am curious to know what makes Robocopy (Robust File Copy) so fast and robust. Any body knows what is the API/Algo used for Robocopy? Anybody studied Robocopy?

I am asking since I have to write a method (in .NET/C#) which will copy directories/files fast and without errors... The amount of data can go up to 15Gb and I cannot simply call Robocopy for various reasons.

Thanks!

Comment: I simply mean as fast as Robocopy. Have you ever compared copying a folder with many gigabytes of data using Windows Explorer and Robocopy? Based on my experience, Robocopy always win.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get very close to Robocopy's speed with a simple C# program that does asynchronous reads and writes using a standard `FileStream` with a 64K buffer.  Larger buffer sizes up to 256K will give a slight performance increase.  Larger than 256K will slow things down to a surprising extent.  In my tests, using a 512K buffer took almost twice as long as copying with a 256K buffer.

The idea is pretty simple:

```
Read the first buffer from the source file
do
{
    start asynchronous write to destination file.
    Read the next buffer from the source file
    wait for asynchronous write to complete
} while not end of file
```

It's a pretty simple thing to write.  My program that does this is almost as fast as Robocopy and doesn't cause the kinds of [problems that Robocopy causes](https://web.archive.org/web/20190309072001/http://blog.mischel.com/2008/10/14/copying-large-files-on-windows/) when you're copying a very large (hundred gigabyte) file from a server.

[A bit more info](https://web.archive.org/web/20160819155058/http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=759) on the large file copy problem.

Note that this asynchronous read/write thing doesn't do much for performance if you're reading from and writing to the same physical disk.  It's most effective when the source and destination are on different drives.